# Баг при использовании in-app purchases

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchases, activityindicator

Использую код для покупок внутри приложении на основе этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51688015). Но столкнулся с некоторыми странными проблемами. Например:

У меня есть `FirstViewController` с заблокированным платным содержимым и `PurchasesViewController` с кнопками покупки. Когда я нажимаю кнопку покупки в `PurchasesViewController`, подтверждаю покупку и жду несколько секунд, чтобы получить уведомление об успешной покупке, а затем я возвращаюсь к `FirstViewController` и вижу, что содержимое разблокировано. В этом примере все работает нормально. Но...

**Проблема:**

Если я нажимаю кнопку покупки в `PurchasesViewController`, подтверждаю покупку и, не дожидаясь уведомления, я возвращаюсь в `FirstViewController` и получаю уведомление об успешной покупке там. Тогда мой контент не будет разблокирован. Даже если я перезапущу приложение, контент не разблокирован все равно. Но если я нажму на кнопку «восстановить покупки», все разблокируется(значит покупка была успешно куплена в первый раз).

Эта проблема может сбивать с толку пользователя. Получается, что они покупают, но контент не получают. А кнопку восстановления не все догадаются нажать. Поэтому как вариант решения, я хочу заблокировать интерфейс и показывать «индикатор активности», пока пользователь не получит уведомление об успешной покупке. Чтобы он не смог перейти в первый контроллер и не произошел баг. И после того, как пользователь нажмет «ОК» в окне уведомления, я хочу разблокировать интерфейс и удалить «индикатор активности». Но как это сделать? Где и когда мне следует вызывать функцию блокировки интерфейса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В указанном промере нет валидации чека.
Но если используется данный пример, то

```
let activitiIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

вызывается в:

```
internal func processPurchaseStatus(_ status: PurchaseStatus) {
        switch status.state {
        case .initiated:
            // тут запускаем индикатор
             activitiIndicator.startAnimating()
        case .complete:
            if let productID = status.transaction?.payment.productIdentifier {
                //тут выключаем
                activitiIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: productID)
            }
        case .cancelled:
            //и тут выключаем, если пользователь прервал покупку
                activitiIndicator.stopAnimating()
        case .failed:
            //тут выключаем если ошибка и сообщаем о ней
            activitiIndicator.stopAnimating()
            print("Ошибка транзакции")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Уже точно так решил вопрос. Да валидация нет. Это большая проблема? Я просто проверяю покупку так `if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchaseName")) { // доступ к контенту }`

Comment: @User пользователь мог отменить покупку в AppStore. Приобрести другую подписку, продлить или не продлить ее. Без валидации чека эту информацию не узнать